# What's the history of Basically Money (this web site)?

Tags: site-information

When was *Basically Money* born, who created it, and what is the purpose of the site?

What makes *Basically Money* different from other money sites or discussion forums?

Comment: FWIW, I created this question originally when the site was launched as http://basicallymoney.com under SE 1.0.  This question was moved over with everything else when the site joined the SE 2.0 network as *money.stackexchange.com*.

Comment: The history of the move might be useful to add, especially since we're nearing graduation.  Congratulations by the way :-).

Answer (score 5):

*(Yes, I'm answering my own question :-)*

I had the idea for **Basically Money** while on vacation in summer 2009.  I was relaxing indoors after a family day at the beach, spending time browsing & answering questions at [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) and [superuser.com](http://superuser.com). I realized it would be great if there were the same kind of Q&A site, but about **money** instead of technology.  Technology is one of my passions -- and **personal finance** the other.

Rather than wait for somebody else to build the community I was looking for, I decided to act.  I requested access to the StackExchange hosted platform beta, which had been recently announced.  StackExchange is based on the same successful software used to run the above sites.

What do I like about the StackExchange platform?  Let me list some of the reasons:

- The *community* decides which questions and answers are good, and which are not, since:
- Questions **and** answers can be either *upvoted* or *downvoted* by registered users.
- Users can gain *reputation* by asking good questions, or providing good answers.
- The system supports organizing questions and finding answers thruogh a tagging system.
- The web site software is a joy to use!

Anyway, here we are.  I hope you enjoy the site!

*Let's build a community together.*